# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в этом предложении?

Tags: запятые

Ты наконец-то пришел, давай иди мой руки и будем ужинать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Ты наконец-то пришел, давай иди мой руки и будем ужинать.***

Запятые расставлены верно.

***Наконец-то*** — обстоятельство времени, не является вводным словом.

Побудительная частица ***ДАВАЙ*** объединяет два односоставных (определенно-личных) предложения (является для них общим элементом), поэтому запятая перед И не ставится.

***Иди мой*** —  простое глагольное сказуемое (осложненная форма), повтор одинаковой формы глагола, обычно для глагола со значением движения или положения.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Запятую можно не ставить, если рассматривать слово "давай" как общее:
*Ты наконец-то пришел, давай иди мой руки и [давай] будем ужинать.*
По смыслу оно равносильно следующему:
*Ты наконец-то пришел, давай помоешь руки и поужинаем.*

Но логичнее поставить запятую, руководствуясь взаимоотношениями следствия:
*Ты наконец-то пришел, давай иди мой руки, и [после этого мы] будем ужинать.*